# Will I lose my windows key (preinstalled to BIOS) if I fully install Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: windows

I'm now the owner of a used Windows 8 laptop, and had planned on ditching Windows in favour of a more secure and ethical OS such as Linux.

Upon receiving the laptop I noticed that it didn't have a Windows key sticker anywhere, and after a bit of searching online I found that Microsoft are now opting to encrypt the windows key in the BIOS (controversial lol).

So if I get rid of Microsoft Windows, and totally replace it with Linux, (I don't want to run them side by side) will the encrypted Windows key be lost, or will I be able to reinstall windows 8 again at a later date? (when I sell the laptop I will want to have it running Windows again).

Comment: Depends, you can if you do not read and understand the install guide. Although rare data loss can happen. Make a windows restore disk and back up your data first.

Comment: This basically is a Windows question and not about Ubuntu. Off topic ;-). But no you will not.

Comment: You *will* need to obtain an OEM install disk for Windows should you wish to reinstall - this is not the vanilla windows that can be purchased from a local store, but should instead be ordered from the computer manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, I'm currently restoring it to its factory settings. *yawn* I will definitely make restore disk, thanks; and hadn't even thought about the install disk.. Although I've always been able to 'find' them floating about in the past. Sorry if this sounds like a Windows question lol but I'd rather talk with Linux people ;) Who knows, maybe this will help someone else 